# why method not allowed exception throwing in symfony server but the code works perfectly fine on local host?

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, laravel-6

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>       The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

This is the error throwing on server but on my localhost there are no errors.

```
<form action="/update-enquiry/{{$msgs->id}}/" method="POST" class="form-horizontal row-fluid">

<!-- <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"> -->
@csrf
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="{{$msgs->name}}" name="name" class="span8" disabled>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Place</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="{{$msgs->place}}" name="place" class="span8" disabled>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Phone</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="{{$msgs->phone}}" name="phone" class="span8" disabled>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Course</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="{{$msgs->course}}" name="course" class="span8" disabled>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Date</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="{{$msgs->created_at}}" name="date" class="span8" disabled>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Status</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8 required" required name="status">
                <option value="{{$msgs->position->id}}" selected>{{$msgs->position->status}}</option>
            @foreach( $positions as $stat)
                <option value="{{$stat->id}}">{{$stat->status}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Remark</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="span8" name="remarks" rows="5">{{$msgs->remarks}}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

this is my form. As you can see only the `remark` input is what im updating. which works perfectly fine on my computer with the method spoofing (which I've commented out to check if it was the cause) and without it.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){

        Route::post('/update-enquiry/{id}',     'AdminController@statusUpdate');
        Route::get('/show-unread',              'AdminController@ShowUnread');
        Route::get('/show-by-status/{id}',      'AdminController@ShowByStatus');
        Route::get('/delete-status/{id}',       'AdminController@DeleteStatus');
        Route::get('/message-delete/{id}',      'AdminController@DeleteMessage');
});
```

this is my route group and to be exact

```php
Route::post('/update-enquiry/{id}',     'AdminController@statusUpdate');
```

is my route. what could be the problem?

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: tried that. still error. @SalmanZafar

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe try `php artisan view:clear` too (on the server ofcourse). Also make sure the HTML output on the server is what you expect with the correct HTTP method. You can also check using your browser developer tools if there is a POST request being made and where to, that might give you the hints you need to hunt this bug down.

Comment: How did you deploy the code to the server? Are you running the route:clear command on the server(not local)?

Comment: What OS is your server running?